# Is it possible to access an external PC instead of a computer with an administrator?(docker swarm)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, docker-swarm

I'm study HyperledgerFabric.
I want to ask some questions.

I referenced this webpage https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f

I have a two PC.

When I turned on two virtual machines on my one PC, I could connect to the worker.

$ docker swarm init
and
$ docker swarm join-token worker
[image]

but I want to access another my PC 
[image]

so I open my port 22,2376,7946(tcp,udp),4789 on two PC

I really want to extra PC join.
How can a join be possible?
also Is it possible?

please tell me
help me please...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
You can refer to my article where I have explained briefly ->
```

https://medium.com/@thotanarendranathreddy/hyperledger-fabric-multi-orgs-multi-nodes-with-kafka-zookeeper-cluster-with-swarm-cluster-5d38be8b1fbc

Answer (score 0):

I have configured this kind of configuration.
If i understood your problem correctly, you want to join two system in one channel of fabric.
For this
Create one node and orderer on one machine and another node on different machine, the orderer IP address i  configtx.yaml should have IP as 
Addresses:
        - 10.64.217.120:7050
Try to join the channel from second machine.
It will work. If not working let me know. I will provide all related config files